# how to build in a form validation

Tags: php

I have been trying to have my form validated, but just nothing happends. I get the form by email no matter whether a field is blank or filled out. Could soemone please look through a php from a php newbie? Where is the bug? i found the php on selfhtml and have modified it for a validitation.

Here is my form:

```
      <form action="../php/terminform_trial.php" method="post" name="termine">
    <dl>
         <dt><label for="name" >Name</label></dt>
         <dd><input type="text" name="name" value=""></dd>

                 <dt><label for="vorname" value="">Vorname</label></dt>
         <dd><input type="text" name="vorname" value=""></dd>

         <dt><label for="geburtsdatum" value="">Geburtsdatum</label></dt>
         <dd><input type="text" name="geburtsdatum" value=""></dd>

         <dt><label for="telefon" value="">Telefon tagsüber </label></dt>
         <dd><input  type="text" name="telefon" value=""></dd>

                 <dt><label for="mobile">Mobile </label></dt>
         <dd><input  type="text" name="mobile" value=""></dd>

         <dt><label for="email">E-Mail Adresse <span class="error"></dt>
         <dd> <input  type="text" name="email" value=""></dd>

           </dl>
        </form>
```

And this is the php I trying out to validate the form.

```
     <?php
     function validateInput($input) {
     if (!preg_match!("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
        {if (empty($_POST["email"]))
            {$emailErr = "Bitte eine gültige E-Mail Adresse eingeben";}// handle error
        }
         else {
              return true;}
        }   

        foreach ($_POST as $fieldname => $value) {
               if (is_array($value))
                {
           foreach ($value as ($einzelwert) === TRUE)
                        {$mailtext .= $fieldname.$seperator.$einzelwert."\n";}
        }   elseif (validateInput($einzelwert))
                        {$mailtext .= $fieldname.$seperator.$value."\n";}

                        }
        mail($myemail, mb_encode_mimeheader
            ($subject, "utf-8", "Q"), 
             $mailtext,
             $header)
         or die("Ihre Nachricht konnte nicht versendet werden.");

         header("Location: http://www.giz-zuerich.ch/_private/sites/danke.html");

      exit;

      }

       header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

      ?>
```

Comment: Rather than rolling your own email validation RegEx, please consider using `filter_var()` instead.

Comment: You can validate the form using Javascript.

Comment: I am real beginner. Could I get more clues?

Comment: @user986959 You could. I could then turn off JavaScript and break your awesome system. Please don't recommend validating exclusively with JS again ;)

Comment: @Ben is filter() also php? if yes, will try to find out google

Comment: If you're a real beginner, Google for a tutorial.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: @Ben do I put the filter () before my array function() or just leave out function'